# drop_duplicates even more for a specific column with latest value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Is there a way to customize drop_duplicates so that it drops the "kind of" duplicates?

Example: pandas df

| Year | Name | ID | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | Superman | 101 | Metropolis |
| 2011 | Batman | 102 | Gotham |
| 2012 | The Batman | 102 | Gotham |
| 2011 | Noobmaster69 | 103 | Online |
| 2011 | Noobmaster69 | 103 | Online |

I tried using drop_duplicates so I got this

| Year | Name | ID | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | Superman | 101 | Metropolis |
| 2011 | Batman | 102 | Gotham |
| 2012 | The Batman | 102 | Gotham |
| 2011 | Noobmaster69 | 103 | Online |

I actually want to squeeze it even more, as I want only "102" row with "The Batman" which is newer info (2012>2011) to be on the data frame. Expecting something like this

| Year | Name | ID | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | Superman | 101 | Metropolis |
| 2012 | The Batman | 102 | Gotham |
| 2011 | Noobmaster69 | 103 | Online |

Comment: No, but you can modify your input so that the "kind of" become equal (e.g. here removing the "The" would do the trick). If you do it as an temporary column/Series, you can even keep the original data.

Comment: Example: `df[~df['Name'].str.replace('The ', '').duplicated(keep='last')]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, duplicates can be easily delete with ID column.

```
import pandas as pd

#reads your table data
read_file = pd.read_csv("your_filename.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(read_file)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='last')
```

`subset = "specific_col"` used to drop the items from the specific column and `keep = "last"` used to keep the last duplicate (removes first duplicate)